# Can a material be diamagnetic to electromagnetic waves, such as the visible spectrum

Tags: electromagnetism

Diamagnetism is shown to repel a magnetic field and therefore the material counterpart of that field. Can an object be diamagnetic to electromagnetic waves, and repel them? I understand that there is a difference between a field and a wave, but not what that difference is.

Comment: Your concept of "material counterpart" seems broken. EM-Waves are just excitations of the EM-Field, so nothing different (just special electromagnetic fields, namely ones possible in a vacuum without sources). And certainly there are materials that "repel waves", look in a mirror. But the mechanism there is usually electrical not magnetic. Furthermore, the usual term is "expels" not "repels", the diamagnet is pushed towards lower field values due to this.

Comment: What i mean by "material counterpart" is, for example, the magnetic properties of a piece iron, coming in to contact with a superconductor, cause the two to repel each other, because the superconductor is diamagnetic. Is the same effect possible with EM-waves like those of the visible spectrum?

Comment: There is radiation pressure exerted on the mirror.

Comment: So the radiation pressure exerted on the mirror, and the EM waves being reflected,is "how" the mirror reflects EM-waves.(in response to the edit of your first comment) diamagnetism "expels" the magnetic field rather than "repels." But the the effect of the diamagnet isn't due to radiation pressure. So the reflection of the mirror and the effect of the diamagnet in a magnetic field are different.

Comment: Certainly a diamagnet will have an effect on electromagnetic waves, but unless it is a superconductor, they won't matter much (just a minor correction of the index of refraction). All other diamagnets are very weakly diamagnetic. Electrical polarization effects will be much stronger and you cannot separate the electric and magnetic field in an EM wave.